# Function to write 2 D Array from java into Excel

Tags: automated-testing, java, excel

I am writing a function which accepts array data as input,and according to the size of array I am filling to excel sheet. Also let me know is there any method get column size of array as array.leght gives row size.
please check the function to write data into excel

```
public class xls_read {
   public String[][] read_xlsx(String filepath, String tab)throws Exception {
        try{                                                                        // create a new "excel" file with location"filename"
        FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));// link "excel" to "program"as InputStream
        XSSFWorkbook xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document);// connect the excel using InputStream
        XSSFSheet xlsx_worksheet = xlsx_workbook.getSheet(tab);// connect to the tab of excel
        int rownum = xlsx_worksheet.getLastRowNum();
        int colnum = xlsx_worksheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        String[][] data = new String[rownum][colnum];
        for (int i = 0; i < rownum; i++) {
            Row row = xlsx_worksheet.getRow(i);
            if (row != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < colnum; j++) {
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        try {
                            data[i][j] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            data[i][j] = new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString().toString().trim();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         return data; 

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("ERROR OCCURED WHILE READING EXCEL"+filepath+e);
        }
        return null;

 }
   public String[][] write_xlsx(String[][] input,String filename,String tabname,int col) {
       System.out.println("input data lenght"+input.length);

       try {
           File excel = new File("E:\\output.xlsx");
           System.out.print("\t"+filename+"\t"+tabname+"\t"+col+input.length+"col"+col+"\n");
           XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
           XSSFSheet sheet= workbook.createSheet();

           // XSSFCell myCell = null;
            String excelData[][] = input;
            System.out.println("lenght excel data"+excelData.length);
            XSSFRow myRow1 = sheet.createRow(input.length);

            /*for (int cellNum = 0; cellNum < col; cellNum++) {
                myCell = myRow1.createCell(cellNum);
                myCell.setCellValue(excelData[0][cellNum]);

            }*/
            XSSFCell myCell = myRow1.createCell(col);
        //    myCell.setCellValue(value)

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    // = myRow1.createCell(i);
                    myCell.setCellValue(input[i][j]);
                    System.out.println(">>"+excelData[i][j]);
                }
            }
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("report genrated..");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: What issue you facing?

Comment: am getting error as,
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip File is closed
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipFileZipEntrySource.getEntries(ZipFileZipEntrySource.java:45)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:186)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:673)

Comment: Can you please specify absolute path for excel file instead of just file name? then run your program.

Comment: i tried putting absolute path but it doesn't work,i am facing same issue.

Comment: Can you please check your POI Jars? make sure that is not corrupted.

Comment: I have changed POI's twice.but of no use. the excel sheet is not getting created

Comment: can you please share whole your code in question ?

Comment: i am getting error at>> write_xlsx fuction.

Comment: If you are creating new sheet by code then you will have to create sheet , row and cell. But here you are using GET method , that looks issue to me.

Comment: with the above code i can create the new excel sheet but with no data init.

Comment: Please check this that how to read/write data in excel using selenium webdriver : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290204/read-and-write-data-to-excel-using-poi-it-deletes-my-original-data-from-excel

Comment: the above link is actually for reading from excel,i need code which write an array into excel.

Comment: Buddy , that provides read and write both..please check id depth.

Comment: here is simple java code which reads/writes data from/in excel files https://github.com/amazpyel/sqa_training/blob/master/HW2/WriteReadExcel.java . I hope it could help you (JXL is required: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ )

Comment: Val, I'm curious if this is a SQA question or more of a general programming question. Could you comment on how it relates to QA specifically? Otherwise, I'll be more than happy to send it to StackOverflow if that's more appropriate.

Comment: hi corsiKa, need to generate report using excel for QA.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, so this definitely needs to be on www.stackoverflow.com` instead of sqa here. Also, when doing so, instead of *just* throwing code up, when you [ask your question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) there, make sure to include what you feel it's doing wrong and what you want it to do - that will help get the right attention you need. I suggest tagging it with [java] and [poi].